# Cronjob in cPanel

Tags: command-line-interface, cron

I'd like to schedule a cronjob on my server to backup the entire public_html directory daily. I am logged into cPanel and I am on the Cron Job page where I have it set to run this command everyday at 2am: `tar -vcf /site_backup.tar /public_html/`

Is this command sufficient for what I want to do? I want to store the contents of public_html in the site_backup.tar that resides in the root directory (one level up from public_html). Do I need to provide anything else in the command for it to run correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command would serve its purpose but is there any reason you aren't using any compression like gzip or bzip? Also since this is in a cron I see no real reason to have the -v flag, no need to see the output.

Just add a -z to your command flags for gzip.

So  your final command would be:

```
tar -zcf /site_backup.tar.gz /public_html/
```

Answer (score 0):

tar cvfz site_backup.tar.gz /path/to/your/user/public_html/ should be enough here, however it's better if you backup this using the cpanel functionality and do it to a remote ftp server.

Additionally you can use something like www.backupsetc.com to backup you cpanel account, using it is pretty straight-forward(you just have to specify your server and accounts to be backed up).